# None jquery placeholder fallback?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a javascript project that provide fallback for the html5 placeholder, but all projects I found are in the form of a jquery plugin, are there any pure JavaScript implement out there?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one myself, and put it on Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/placeholder-fixer/

Comment: it doesn't seem to handle the form submission case.